# I can't figure out this error using time() in python

Tags: python, time

Here is my code:

```
# Given an Unix timestamp in milliseconds (ts), return a human-readable date and time (hrdt)
def parseTS(ts):
  hrdt = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", time.time(int(ts)/1000))
  return str(hrdt)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: time() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

**UPDATE:**

This worked:

```
hrdt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)//1000)
return hrdt
```

Comment: Nitpick: `int(ts)/1000` is an outdated way to do floor division. Use `ts // 1000` to make sure your code will work correctly in future Python versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time.time(int(ts)/1000) function is wrong.

Try one of time.ctime, time.gtime() or time.localtime() functions to achieve what you want.

[Python Docs (Time)](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html)

Comment: I don't want to change the timezone, though. I want to represent the timestamp as is, which should be in UTC/GMT. Which of these will not change the timestamp based on the system's local time settings?

Comment: time.ctime()then.  No locale information is used to convert the time

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but kept getting various errors. For some reason ctime wants a 9-digit timestamp, but unix gives 10-digit ones. So I ended going with the changes above.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, time.time() doesn't take any arguments, it just returns current time as floating point.  Maybe you are thinking of time.ctime()?

Comment: I don't want to change the timezone, though. I want to represent the timestamp as is, which should be in UTC/GMT. Which of these will not change the timestamp based on the system's local time settings?

Comment: I am passing a timestamp to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
time.time(int(ts)/1000)
```

And (as the error is telling you), [time() takes no arguments](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time).

It's unclear what you're trying to do, but maybe you want:

```
int(time.time() / 1000)
```

Or just `int(time.time())` if you want the time in seconds without the floating point part.

Comment: I am passing it a timestamp. I don't want to change the timezone, though. I want to represent the timestamp as is, which should be in UTC/GMT. Which of these will not change the timestamp based on the system's local time settings?